# Permutation and Combinations Choosing out of a Pool of People

Tags: permutations

Two students are to be randomly selected from a pool of N students, n of whom study maths. If it is known that at least one student studies maths, what is the chance that both students study mathematics?

A.$$\frac {n-1} {2N-n-1} $$
B.$$\frac {n-1} {2N+n+1} $$
C.$$\frac {n-1} {2N+n-1} $$
D.$$\frac {n-1} {2N-n+1} $$

Not quite sure how to get the multiple choice but I thought you only have to do out of the n-1 you choose 1, and you divide it by N-1 C 1 to get the probability.

Comment: Let $A$ be the event that at least one studies maths.  Let $B$ be the event that both study maths.  We are asked to find $Pr(B\mid A)$ which by definition is $\frac{Pr(B\cap A)}{Pr(A)}$ which as $B\subseteq A$ simplifies to be $\frac{Pr(B)}{Pr(A)}$.  Now... can you find $Pr(\text{both study math})$ and $Pr(\text{at least one studies math})$?  Either counting approaches or straight probability approaches are fine here.

Comment: As an aside, $\frac{\binom{n-1}{1}}{\binom{N-1}{1}}=\frac{n-1}{N-1}$ is the probability that both study maths given that *the first student* studies maths where we picked the students in sequence, which is different than "*at least one*" student studies maths.

Comment: nC2 / {nC1 x N-n+1C1 + nC2}

Comment: And that gives out A which is correct

Comment: Since you figured out the solution, I suggest you answer your own question so that it can be closed.